Gulp stream bytes differ from real contents
function fn(buff, file) {
  console.log(buff);                 << FORWARDED by gulp
  let data = readFile(file.path);    
  console.log(data);                 << REAL FILE content
  return data;
}

gulp.task('default', () {
  return gulp
    .src('src/*.png')
    .pipe(transform(fn))
    .pipe(dest)
});

The content of the buffers buff, and data differ. I am unable to understand why.
